# How to extract values from a JSON file using PowerShell under certain conditions?

Tags: json, powershell

The goal is to get the values of keys `name`, `extension` and `fileinfo` for each entry in the JSON file if the following conditions are met:

- The key `change_flag` has the value `TRUE`
- The key `unpack` has the value `TRUE`

Example: The above conditions are met for the entry with the name `zipzoom`, hence, I should get for this entry the values of keys `name`, `extension` and `fileinfo`.

My JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "name": "kernel",
    "change_flag": "FALSE",
    "unpack": "FALSE",
    "extension": "jar",
    "fileinfo": [
      {
        "localPath": "Local path",
        "fileName": "kernel.jar",
        "filePath": "setupfiles\\controlroom"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "activemq",
    "change_flag": "FALSE",
    "unpack": "FALSE",
    "extension": "jar",
    "fileinfo": [
      {
        "localPath": "Local path",
        "fileName": "activemq.jar",
        "filePath": "setupfiles\\controlroom"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "certmgr",
    "change_flag": "FALSE",
    "unpack": "FALSE",
    "extension": "jar",
    "fileinfo": [
      {
        "localPath": "Local path",
        "fileName": "certmgr.jar",
        "filePath": "setupfiles\\controlroom"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "zipzoom",
    "extension": "jar",
    "change_flag": "TRUE",
    "unpack": "TRUE",
    "fileinfo": [
      {
        "localPath": "Local path",
        "fileName": "zipzoom.jar",
        "filePath": "destpath1"
      },
      {
        "localPath": "Local path",
        "fileName": "localpath2\\file2",
        "filePath": "destpath2\\"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is JSON, you can use the `ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlet to convert it to an array of PSObjects and use a `Where-Object` clause to filter the objects you need:

```
$json = @'
[
  {
    "name": "kernel",
    "change_flag": "FALSE",
    "unpack": "FALSE",
    "extension": "jar",
    "fileinfo": [
      {
        "localPath": "Local path",
        "fileName": "kernel.jar",
        "filePath": "setupfiles\\controlroom"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "activemq",
    "change_flag": "FALSE",
    "unpack": "FALSE",
    "extension": "jar",
    "fileinfo": [
      {
        "localPath": "Local path",
        "fileName": "activemq.jar",
        "filePath": "setupfiles\\controlroom"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "certmgr",
    "change_flag": "FALSE",
    "unpack": "FALSE",
    "extension": "jar",
    "fileinfo": [
      {
        "localPath": "Local path",
        "fileName": "certmgr.jar",
        "filePath": "setupfiles\\controlroom"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "zipzoom",
    "extension": "jar",
    "change_flag": "TRUE",
    "unpack": "TRUE",
    "fileinfo": [
      {
        "localPath": "Local path",
        "fileName": "zipzoom.jar",
        "filePath": "destpath1"
      },
      {
        "localPath": "Local path",
        "fileName": "localpath2\\file2",
        "filePath": "destpath2\\"
      }
    ]
  }
]
'@

$result = ($json | ConvertFrom-Json) | 
     Where-Object { $_.change_flag -eq 'TRUE' -and $_.unpack -eq 'TRUE' } | 
     Select-Object name, extension, fileinfo

# output
$result
```

Output on screen:

```
name    extension fileinfo                                                                                                                                    
----    --------- --------                                                                                                                                    
zipzoom jar       {@{localPath=Local path; fileName=zipzoom.jar; filePath=destpath1}, @{localPath=Local path; fileName=localpath2\file2; filePath=destpath2\}}
```

Because the `fileinfo` parts are also objects with properties of their own, if you want to get them individually, you can do:

```
$result[0].fileinfo   # get the object by index
```

Or filter the object by name:

```
($result | Where-Object { $_.name -eq 'zipzoom' }).fileinfo
```

to return

```
localPath  fileName         filePath  
---------  --------         --------  
Local path zipzoom.jar      destpath1 
Local path localpath2\file2 destpath2\
```

Comment: Let me try, back to you if needed thank you appreciated much explanation.                               Just one more thing can I loop into fileinfo. Because this info might change in future and I might have more file info